# a coding theory question about inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, coding-theory

Let $F$ be a finite
collection of binary strings of finite lengths, and assume that no two distinct
concatenations of two finite sequences of codewords result in the same binary
sequence. Let $N_i$ denote the number of strings of length $i$ in $F$. Prove that$$\sum_{i}{\frac{N_i}{2^i}}\le{1}$$

Comment: Look up Kraft's Inequality.

Comment: they seem different

Comment: this looks stronger @Batman